# Is Gitlab 'lock file' functionality supposed to be bidirectional?

Tags: gitlab, git-lfs

I'm experimenting with the [File Lock](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/file_lock.html) mechanism, and it's unclear to me whether if the edition of locks between the CLI and Gitlab UI is supposed to be bidirectional or not.

By default, unlocked files are readonly. This matches what `ls -la` tells me

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 200207121 1049089     0 Sep 13 13:49 .git/
-rw-r--r-- 1 200207121 1049089  2738 Sep 13 13:02 .gitattributes
-r--r--r-- 1 200207121 1049089 90299 Sep 13 13:26 My_locked_file.docx
-rw-r--r-- 1 200207121 1049089  1118 Sep 13 13:02 README.md
```

Let's say I lock a file through the CLI. The Gitlab UI will show the file has been locked properly, and the permission for the file is locally set to read/write.

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 200207121 1049089     0 Sep 13 13:26 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 200207121 1049089     0 Sep 13 13:02 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 200207121 1049089     0 Sep 13 13:49 .git/
-rw-r--r-- 1 200207121 1049089  2738 Sep 13 13:02 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r-- 1 200207121 1049089 90299 Sep 13 13:26 My_locked_file.docx
-rw-r--r-- 1 200207121 1049089  1118 Sep 13 13:02 README.md
```

However, if I unlock it **from the Gitlab UI**, it's not unlocked on my local CLI. And I'm unsure if this is the intended behaviour or not.

Even with `git checkout .` or `git pull` , I can't figure out how to 'locally refresh' the locks, to specify it has been released. The lock remains closed locally no matter what.

Comment: It's a mechanism of git lfs. Maybe try `git lfs pull` or `git lfs fetch` ?

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't do the trick. Removing the lock on Gitlab UI still shows the file locked locally even after `git lfs pull` or `git lfs fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old thread, just adding gitlab support answer for future reference:

> GitLab Support Feb 8, 2024, 21:53 UTC
> Hello Eyal,    Thanks for
> reaching out with your file-locking questions.
>
> Use file lock using Exclusive files locks via the command line or use
> Default branch file locks via the UI.
>
> Exclusive Files: Use the
> command line, not the UI. You install git-lfs then configure your
> locked files. Afterward, you can use git lfs lock and git lfs unlock
> To view exclusively locked files you would run git lfs locks. There
> should be no need to use the GUi after you enabled the lock feature
> the first time.
>
> Default Branch locks: Allow you to lock one  file
> at a time via the Gitlab UI. Default branch file and directory locks
> only apply to the default branch set in the project’s settings. Since
> they are locked in the UI you wont be able to view them via command on
> your local computer.  Instead, you would want to look in the UI under
> your project under Code > Locked files.